# How to setup python 2.7 features into Python 2.6?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.6 in Windows environment for my current work. But i am interested in some features which were added in Python 2.7. 
Is it possible to move some features(particularly "Collections.OrderedDict") from 2.7 to 2.6? If so how can we do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict

It's advertised as

> A drop-in substitute for Py2.7's new collections.OrderedDict that
>   works in Python 2.4-2.6.

Comment: Got it the package.May i know How to setup in windows OS? Whether I have to paste that file in site-packages? or Is there any other way to install it?

Comment: thanks ..I used cmd to install it. and also we have the difference like "from collections import OrderedDict"<2.7> and from ordereddict import OrderedDict<2.6> pypi ;-)